# Stop a 'falsy' alert after a correct prompt in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, alert

After answering the prompt correctly, the alert-message for wrong answer still appear after the right answer is given. I don't seem to find why nor how to terminate the second alert.

```js
var userResponse = prompt("Hello, please enter the capital of Massachusetts?");

if(userResponse === "Boston") {
     alert("Yes! Boston is the right answer");
   };

if(userResponse === "Albany"){
   alert("I am sorry, but Albany is rather the capital of NY");
}

else {
      alert("I am sorry, but" + userResponse + " is not the right answer."); 
     };
```

Comment: Use `else if` for the second `if`.

Comment: This fixed it!!! Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

Bad formatting / code style and a missing `else`:

```js
var userResponse = prompt("Hello, please enter the capital of Massachusetts?");
if (userResponse === "Boston") {
  alert("Yes! Boston is the right answer");
} else if (userResponse === "Albany") {
  alert("I am sorry, but Albany is rather the capital of NY");
} else {
  alert("I am sorry, but " + userResponse + " is not the right answer."); 
}
```

Also note semicolons (`;`) are not necessary after code blocks (`{}`). In fact, in your case, one would have broken your `if`-`else if` chain.

Comment: Yesss! It was indeed the "else if" and the extra semi-colon. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works! I think you must be simply typing it in wrong since it is case sensitive. I would add this so that it is not case sensitive:

```
if (userResponse === "Boston" || userResponse === "boston") {
```

Now you can type `boston` instead of only being able to type `Boston`. My recommendation is to never make the answer only case sensitive! In this case, it will say `I am sorry, but boston is not the right answer.`, when it is totally correct

And make sure to add `else` on the second possibility as @AurelBily pointed out!